# bxslider - Why does my slider gets faster with more items, and slower with less?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, slider, bxslider

https://waveoptiks.com/

```
            jQuery('.homepage_slider').bxSlider(
                {
                    minSlides: 1,
                    maxSlides: 4,
                    slideWidth: 200,
                    slideMargin: 30,
                    shrinkItems: true,
                    ticker: true,
                    speed: 50000,
                    easing: 'ease-in',
                    tickerHover: 1,
                    adaptiveHeight: 1,
                }
            );
```

When the slider has a lot of list items, it is extremely fast, but when you remove items, it gets slower. If seems like the slider cycle is trying to get through the entire list in a set amount of time and will speed up the slider to do so. Am I missing a setting, or is there a conflict with another plugin?

Comment: Willing to pay for a fix

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether you've found a good workaround, but your comment on it 'seems like the slider cycle is trying to get through the entire list in a set amount of time' gave me some insight into how to solve this problem for my bxslider.

In the bxSlider v.4.2.12, there is a function in the jquery.bxslider.js used to set the tickerLoop variable. Instead of:

```
var tickerLoop = function(resumeSpeed) {
  var speed = resumeSpeed ? resumeSpeed : slider.settings.speed,
```

I changed it to:

```
var tickerLoop = function(resumeSpeed) {
  var speed = resumeSpeed ? resumeSpeed : slider.settings.speed * slider.children.length,
```

I had to adjust the speed on my bxslider, but the change allows the slider to ticker at a consistent rate.

Comment: I believe that's something similar to what I ended up doing as well. Glad I could help ;)